# Stringifying a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, json

Of course, JSON does not support Regex literals.

So,

```
JSON.stringify(/foo/)
```

gives:

```
{ }
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is the closest you can get:

```
RegExp.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.source; };

JSON.stringify({ re: /foo/ }); // { "re": "foo" }
```

Comment: +1, except that it doesn't give you modifiers. You'd need to add those with `+ (this.global ? "g" : "")` and so on.

Comment: What @BlueSkies said. :) Or you could use `.toString`, I believe it gives you everything. The idea was just to demonstrate how you can force RegExps to be able to go JSON on their own.

Comment: Wouldn't using a replacer function be preferable to modifying `RegExp.prototype` (and breaking encapsulation)?

Comment: This is much cleaner IMO. It would be unfortunate to have to test every value just in case there's a regexp there, when it could be avoided. That's why they give us the `.toJSON` option.

Comment: @BlueSkies, I guess it depends on where the code it supposed to run. If it's just a one-shot deal on someone's own site, modifying global prototypes is fine, but if it's meant to be portable, it's probably not too good (think prototype.js)

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Yeah, not good for a public library (unless it's well documented anyway), but I kind of doubt that's what OP is doing. Good point though.

Comment: The big question next should be: How to you JSON.parse() the output efficiently and most importantly without restricting patterns in plain string values?

Comment: Modifying built-in prototypes is considered harmful or: "with great power comes great responsibility". Using a specific function / parameters for a specific case, as OP wants to convert RegEx on using `JSON.stringify()`just as @FelixKling is proposing, is the better and cleaner solution. This proposed solutions has potentially side-effects.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a a [custom replacer function to `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) and convert the regular expression to a string (assuming that the expression is part of an array or object):

```
JSON.stringify(value, function(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof RegExp) {
        return value.toString();
    }
    return value;
});
```

If you don't actually want/need to create JSON, just call the `toString()` method of the expression.

Comment: does `instanceof RegExp` work reliably now days? Some browsers used to treat regex as instances of Function IIRC

Comment: @Dagg: I am not aware of that issue, so I don't know.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: That was `typeof`, and was in old versions of Chrome.

Comment: @BlueSkies, that could be it, although I'm pretty sure Safari was the culprit in the case I'm thinking of.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Safari 11+ returns true for `/foo/ instanceof RegExp`

Answer (score 2):

Although JavaScript objects allow you to put regex as values, JSON does not  as it is meant to store only data, not code.

As a workaround, you could convert your regular expression to a string using the `toString()` method.

```
var str = /([a-z]+)/.toString(); // "/([a-z]+)/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) function:

```
JSON.stringify(/foo/, 
    function(k, v) { 
        if (v && v.exec == RegExp.prototype.exec) return '' + v; 
        else return v; 
    })
```

Comment: That isn't really enough of a test. It'll mess up any other object with a truthy `.source` property. And you're not providing a default return value.

Comment: Almost. You'll need to make sure that `v` isn't `null` or `undefined`. ;)

Comment: Man, you're on top of it. Fixed again. And TIL JSON.stringify converts undefined to null, never noticed that.