# How to parse a regex text with Json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have this string that I want to convert to an JSON object, the problem is that one of the fields of the object is a regex:

```
"{
     \"regex\": /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\-\\+%])+\\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-])+\\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,
     \"alertText\": \"test\"
}"
```

Is there a way to get the JavaScript object without doing hundreds of replaces?

EDIT: I use the following code to store the correct serialized version of the original object from [Stringifying a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276531/stringifying-a-regular-expression):

```
RegExp.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.source; };
```

Then I could modify the content of the string:

```
{"regex":"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\-\\+%])+\\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-])+\\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$","alertText":"* {{alertText}}"}
```

So I can use it as a template, and then, when needed, JSON.parse the string to get a new object.

Comment: I'd like to see more of the JS and HTML behind how you get this.. the CRLF characters are making this unnecessarily complex

Comment: What serialized it into a string in the first place?  Reason for asking: does it have a parsing counterpart you can use?

Comment: Shouldn't the regex value be enclosed in quotes also? Looks like you need a couple of extra `\"` characters.

Comment: If you go this demo example: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html and check: $("form").data('jqv').allrules.email thats a validation object. I want to dinamically add a new rule with a different alertText stored on SQL. So after modifying the base type to get my own one, I want to  $("form").data('jqv').allrules["myNewValidation"] = JSON.parse(stringFromSQL) to insert the new rule dynamically

Comment: Regex doesn't need to be enclosed in quotes in JavaScript, but JSON doesn't support Regex literals. Write a prototype function to convert your regex to and from JSON strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276531/stringifying-a-regular-expression.

Comment: @AkshayShenoy you can use `unescape()`

Comment: You do not have JSON as you have a non-scalar value (the regex literal). You need to ensure that 1) you are generating your JSON with appropriate serialization techniques as opposed to manually producing 2) use a string to represent the regex, and "wake it up" by passing it to JS's RegExp constructor when you're ready to use it.

Comment: What language are you using on the server? This looks to be an issue about JSON serializing some data from SQL.

Comment: c# using rest web api MVC

Comment: Thanks Anton, ny initial problem is that json.stringify didnt work correctly with a regex so I stored the object constructor as code. But then I had the issue with the parse... On that link, with the regex prototype, I can create a correct JSON.stringify version of the regex object to be used after modifications on JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure that your regex value is enclosed with quotes to force it to be a string value:

```
"{
     \"regex\": \"/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\-\\+%])+\\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-])+\\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/\",
     \"alertText\": \"test\"
}"
```

Then, this will parse as a JSON object correctly and you can get the regex out later to create your regex from it.

If you require the slashes double escaped for your regex purposes, then...

```
 "{
     \"regex\": \"/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\.\\\\-\\\\+%])+\\\\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-])+\\\\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/\",
     \"alertText\": \"test\"
}"
```

Comment: It still doesn't parse. `VM1526:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: That's probably because you will need to double-double those backslashes now it's in a regex in a string

Comment: Thanks. I simply got it to parse as JSON in the initial example, which is fine. The parsing of the regex thereafter, is a separate issue. I've amended the answer to cover that subsequent issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

One alternative solution whould be to change/reformat your JSON string, you will simply need to :

- Change the enclosing double quotes `"` with a single quote `'`.
- And use only one backslash `\` for escaping.

This is a working DEMO:

```js
var text = '{"regex": "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+%])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/", "alertText": "test"}';
var obj=JSON.parse(text);

console.dir(obj);
document.write(obj.regex);
document.write("<br>"+obj.alertText);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @randomsock well the question was to parse the Javascript object, and that's what I suggested.

Comment: Actually no, you've shown one way of changing the data so that it can be parsed, not how to parse the data the OP has.  The question was how to parse what's there without having to do text edits.

Comment: @randomsock fair point, you are right about it, but I don't think this deserves all these downvotes.

Comment: @randomsock Thank you for pointing this out, your comments were very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is No.

Answers so far rely on being able to change the string at source.  If you can do that, great, but as per the OP, you can't parse the JSON with a regex value using a stock JSON.parse(), even with a reviver function.